# webdriver, mocha, проблема с открытием окон браузера в цикле

Tags: javascript, selenium, frontend, test-automation, mocha

**Вот рабочий код:**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var browser = webdriverio.remote({desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'chrome'}});
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');

describe('Prepare data, enter the site and search', function () {
    this.timeout(60000);

    var testData = [];

    it('should prepare data', function(done) {
        var prepareData = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(error, data){
            testData = data;
        });
        fs.createReadStream('./data/rtk/testCodes.csv').pipe(prepareData);
        browser.call(done);
    });

    it('should open browser', function(done) {
        browser
            .init()
            .url('http://ru.stackoverflow.com/')
            .call(done);
   });
});
```

Далее мне необходимо открыть столько окон браузера, сколько элементов в массиве `testData`. В каждом из окон нужно открыть определённый сайт.

**Пишу следующий код:**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var browser = webdriverio.remote({desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'chrome'}});
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');

describe('Prepare data, enter the site and search', function () {
    this.timeout(60000);

    var testData = [];

    it('should prepare data', function(done) {
        var prepareData = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(error, data){
            testData = data;
        });
        fs.createReadStream('./data/rtk/testCodes.csv').pipe(prepareData);
        browser.call(done);
    });

    it('should open browser', function(done) {
        testData.forEach(function(direction) {
            console.log(direction);
        browser
            .init()
            .url('http://mts.bol24.ru/')
            .call(done);
    });
});
```

**В итоге:**

`console.log()` выводит нужное кол-во элементов,
запускается нужное число окон браузера,
в первом сайт открывается,
в остальных - пустые окна

С чем это может быть связано?